# Change array index over time in WebGL shader code

Tags: glsl, webgl, glsles

I'm trying to change the index of a texture array over time. This is  part of a WebGL GLSL fragment shader. The array has a length of 22 and I have to variables to determine how far along it should be. I was trying to do something like this.

```
float positionInTime = (currentAge / duration);
positionInTime /= 0.04545;
positionInTime = sign(positionInTime)*floor(abs(positionInTime)+0.5);
highp int arrayPosition = int(positionInTime);
vec4 rotatedTexture = texture2D( texture[arrayPosition], rotatedUV );
```

But it would seem I have to use a constant for the index. How can I go about changing the index over time?

Comment: I take it this is for OpenGL ES? There is a requirement there that arrays be indexed using const-index expressions. In desktop OpenGL, it is perfectly fine to index a uniform array with a non-const expression. But if your array has a length of 22, that's probably going to cause problems whether you're running on desktop GL or ES, because they are only required to support 16 and 8 samplers per-stage respectively.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that i'm using WebGL. I can adjust the length of the array if needed. What i'm having issues with is just the basic concept of expressing the change over time. I'm getting an error stating that the index has to be a constant. I primarily code JavaScript. Which does not have this constraint.